# Как вызвать функцию из внешнего JS файла

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Пишу в начале `html` документа:

```
<script src=js/JS_req.js></script>
```

Ниже вызываю функцию:

```
<button type=submit class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss=modal onclick = 'login_1()'>Увійти</button>
```

Объявлю в `JS` файле:

```
function login_1() {
alert("Авторизация временно недоступна")};
```

А дебагер пишет:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: login_1 is not defined

(ругается на строчку где я вызвал его по `onClick`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может, браузер закэшировал старый вариант файла `js/JS_req.js`? И лучше заключать в кавычки имя файла и прочие значения HTML атрибутов. Не обязательно, но лучше.

Считается неудачной практикой писать обработчики прямо в теле HTML, лучше навешивать слушатели событий:

```
<button id="btn-exit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">
    Увійти
</button>
// ...
<script>
    document
      .getElementById('btn-exit')
      .addEventListener('click', function(){
        alert("Авторизация временно недоступна"); 
      })
    ;
</script>
```

В таком варианте скрипт нужно подключать в конце документа, перед закрывающим `</body>`.

Comment: как я понял, скрипт нужно все равно пихать в html файл, но у меня есть и тяжелые скрипты, которые не желательно нагружать на клиента

Comment: в конце (а не в начале) документа подключайте внешний скрипт – как и раньше, только в конец перенесите. Т.к. сначала нужно, чтобы точно была в документе кнопка с нужным id, а только потом навешивать на неё слушатель событий.

Comment: Как самое короткое решение вашей исходной проблемы, попробуйте просто дописать случайный параметр к адресу скрипта, чтобы он точно обновился с сервера: `<script src="js/JS_req.js?42" ... `

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать добавить id вашей кнопке, например, id="login", а затем добавить обработчик нажатия.

```
<script>
    var button = document.getElementById("login");
    button.onclick = function() {  
        // ...                          
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Наверно, ты используешь функцию ДО того, как скрипт загрузился. Браузер натыкается на

```js
<script src=js/JS_req.js></script>
```

посылает запрос на сервер и погнал дальше анализировать код. Причем, код *очень* быстро анализируется и выполняется. Поэтому, браузер успевает "добежать" по коду до вызова функции, а скрипт с ней еще не успел загрузиться и, значит, не проанализирован - твоя функция еще не занесена прелоадсканнером в соответствующий объект-контекст исполнения кода.

С ходу придумал такой вариант - сделать сетинтервал, который будет проверять, а определена ли функция login_1() каждые сколько-то (например, 100) миллисекунд. если определена, то она выполняется и сетинтервал удаляется.

Answer (score -1):

Добавьте `<script src=js/JS_req.js></script>` в конце документа ( перед закрывающимся тегом `</body>` ).

Comment: вот как раз с инлайн-обработчиками эти советы не помогут

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо, теперь буду знать)

Comment: не, в конце документа тоже не поможет, потому что при инлайн обработчиках функция должна быть объявлена _до_ использования